# Length of output of AES 128 encryption in python

Tags: python, encryption, hex, aes, pycrypto

When I am trying to convert to hex the output of my AES 128 encryption code using pycrypto. I am using hexlify .the output is 64 bits for a 32 bits input.  The output is always double the size for any input and when  use an online compiler I get a perfect 32 bit output.Whats the wrong

What format should i convert the data to get the same size as the input while implementing it.

```
text= 3235383334332b352b3934363230383037312b3100000000

key ='0123456789abcdef'

iv = '/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00'

encryptor = AES.new(key,mode,IV=iv)

output=encryptor.encrypt(text)
```

I get encrypted output as

```
?"?χ?v???
         ؛?3(???nyA??U?}??/??>
```

I wanted to convert it into a format where i could read it hence was converting it hex

```
efb82283cf87e7127696baad0c1bd89b3781331c289db9f96e7941d3cd55c77db8a72fdcdd3e1ac1bc9031c61c998e49
```

can you suggest some other readable format to which i could convert my data to??

Comment: Please provide some code that demonstates your problem, example inputs, outputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Why does it have to be the same size? Hex would be the standard for making it readable. A lot better than binary or octal.

Answer (score 1):

I quote from the [python documentation for binascii.hexlify](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) (emphasis added):

> Return the hexadecimal representation of the binary data. Every byte of data is converted into the corresponding 2-digit hex representation. **The resulting string is therefore twice as long as the length of data**.

> What format should i convert the data to get the same size as the input while implementing it.

Don't convert it at all. Just write it as binary data.